# Get Workflow current state ID of a node

Tags: 7, nodes, workflows

I'm trying to get current workflow state of a node to use in a function which will disable some tabs according to conditions.

```
$current_state = workflow_node_current_state($node)
```

didn't work. So, I coded a custom module contains:

```
function mycheck() {
  global $user;
  $node = node_load($node->nid)

  if (intval($node->workflow) = 3) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The module at Drupal crashes... How can I get current workflow state of a node to use in a function (to use in a custom module) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get from `dpm(workflow_node_current_state($node))` (assuming you have Devel installed) after loading the node object inside `mycheck()`? (By the way, it's always best to prefix your functions with the name of your custom module. It's possible it's "crashing" due to a namespace conflict.)